# TeX and derivatives tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

In TeX.SX the tags XeTeX and XeLaTeX are the same, but there is a big diference between this two topics, so when we look for something specific we get also results of little help. The same case happens with LaTeX an TeX. Thus splitting in two separate tags is of use, more opinions like this one?

Comment: The one tag is to separate problems specific to Xe* from problems unrelated to Xe*. Use other tags to speficy what the problem is exactly.

Comment: Feel free to ask on TeX-sx meta: it comes down to the fact that we _don't_ tag for 'LaTeX' as its  by far the dominant TeX format, so `xetex` as a tag means the question is about that engine in some way, while something like `plain-tex` as well would mean it's not about XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 16):

The tagging approach taken here is quite deliberate. Whilst TeX-sx covers the TeX world generally, LaTeX is by far the dominant format in use (plain TeX and ConTeXt are much less widely used). As such, it was clear from the earliest days of the site that questions should be treated as about LaTeX *unless* they are explicitly not. Thus we have tags such as [plain-tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plain-tex) and [context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context), plus for low-level questions [tex-core](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex-core).

For engine variation, we have tags [pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdftex), [xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xetex) and [luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luatex). These are used to show that a question is about that engine specifically but *do not* specify which format is involved. Thus a question which is about a questions specific to using the plain format with the XeTeX engine should be tagged both [xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xetex) and [plain-tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plain-tex). (The latter tag is used not just for Knuth's TeX90 format but any of the 'essentially plain' derivatives.) On the other hand, a question specific to XeLaTeX should be tagged [xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xetex) plus whatever packages are important (likely to be [fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fontspec) or perhaps [fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts), though it could be of course a question about drivers or the like).

Comment: So if I want to search about the fonts in XeLaTeX I use the tags {xetex} and {fonts}, and I get a lot of results of no use.

Comment: @BrianMayer Probably you search for [tag:fontspec] and [tag:xetex]: [tag:fonts] is one of those rather general tags that don't necessarily narrow things down a lot. (That said, doing [that search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts+xetex) for me has lots of hits about font issues in XeLaTeX.)